# Project on update/create (set values from another object en masse) in LINQ2DB?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, dto, projection, linq2db

When using LINQ2DB for my application I tried to use entity-DTO mapping using `Expression<Func<Entity, DTO>>` and vice versa like described here: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/1283#issuecomment-413509043

This works great for projecting using a select, but what do I do when I need to update/insert a new record? I've skimmed over Update and Set extension methods but couldn't find anything.

What I am trying to achieve is basically expression-based two-way mapping between an entity class and a DTO, kinda like AutoMapper's projection for EF but manually written per-DTO, in the form of two expressions for two-way conversion.

Sadly I am not an expert in expression trees and LINQ to SQL translation, so would appreciate if anyone suggests something that works like this:

```cs
Expression<Func<SomeDTO, SomeEntityTable>> projectExpr =
    x => new SomeEntity
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Name = x.Name,
        // ...
    }; // this is just so that I can write two mapping expressions per DTO and don't ever repeat them, for stuff like CRUD

// ...

using var db = ConnectionFactory.Instance.GetMainDB();
await db.SomeEntityTable
    .Where(e => e.ID == dto.ID)
    .Set(dto, projectExpr) // dto is of SomeDTO type here; this will set ONLY the values that are written in the expression
    .Set(e => e.LastEditedAt, DateTime.Now()) // able to append some more stuff after 
    .UpdateAsync();


// similar for insert operation, using the same expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These extension methods should provide needed mapping:

```cs
using var db = ConnectionFactory.Instance.GetMainDB();

await db.SomeEntityTable
    .Where(e => e.ID == dto.ID)
    .AsUpdatable()
    .Set(dto, projectExpr) // new extension method
    .Set(e => e.LastEditedAt, DateTime.Now())
    .UpdateAsync();

await db.SomeEntityTable
    .AsValueInsertable()
    .Values(dto, projectExpr) // new extension method
    .Value(e => e.LastEditedAt, DateTime.Now())
    .InsertAsync();
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class InsertUpdateExtensions
{
    private static MethodInfo _withIUpdatable       = Methods.LinqToDB.Update.SetUpdatableExpression;
    private static MethodInfo _withIValueInsertable = Methods.LinqToDB.Insert.VI.ValueExpression;

    public static IUpdatable<TEntity> Set<TEntity, TDto>(
        this IUpdatable<TEntity>        updatable, 
        TDto                            obj,
        Expression<Func<TDto, TEntity>> projection)
    {
        var body = projection.GetBody(Expression.Constant(obj));

        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");

        var pairs = EnumeratePairs(body, entityParam);

        foreach (var pair in pairs)
        {
            updatable = (IUpdatable<TEntity>)_withIUpdatable.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity), pair.Item1.Type)
                .Invoke(null,
                    new object?[]
                    {
                        updatable, 
                        Expression.Lambda(pair.Item1, entityParam), 
                        Expression.Lambda(pair.Item2)
                    })!;
        }

        return updatable;
    }

    public static IValueInsertable<TEntity> Values<TEntity, TDto>(
        this IValueInsertable<TEntity>  insertable, 
        TDto                            obj,
        Expression<Func<TDto, TEntity>> projection)
    {
        var body = projection.GetBody(Expression.Constant(obj));

        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");

        var pairs = EnumeratePairs(body, entityParam);

        foreach (var pair in pairs)
        {
            insertable = (IValueInsertable<TEntity>)_withIValueInsertable.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity), pair.Item1.Type)
                .Invoke(null,
                    new object?[]
                    {
                        insertable, 
                        Expression.Lambda(pair.Item1, entityParam), 
                        Expression.Lambda(pair.Item2)
                    })!;
        }

        return insertable;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Tuple<Expression, Expression>> EnumeratePairs(Expression projection, Expression entityPath)
    {
        switch (projection.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.MemberInit:
            {
                var mi = (MemberInitExpression)projection;
                foreach (var b in mi.Bindings)
                {
                    if (b.BindingType == MemberBindingType.Assignment)
                    {
                        var assignment = (MemberAssignment)b;
                        foreach (var p in EnumeratePairs(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityPath, assignment.Member),
                                        assignment.Expression))
                        {
                            yield return p;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            case ExpressionType.New:
            {
                var ne = (NewExpression)projection;
                if (ne.Members != null)
                {
                    for (var index = 0; index < ne.Arguments.Count; index++)
                    {
                        var expr   = ne.Arguments[index];
                        var member = ne.Members[index];

                        foreach (var p in EnumeratePairs(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityPath, member), expr))
                        {
                            yield return p;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(projection, entityPath);
                break;

            }
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```